# Delete a favorites folder, but keep the favorites?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I just imported my favorites from Internet Explorer into Firefox, and it put it into a folder on the favorites bar, instead of just putting all of my favorites on the bar itself. Is there anyway to move them all out of that folder, without dragging them out one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Show all bookmarks" on the bookmark menu, you can select multiple bookmarks and cut and paste them.